# Is there a way in which I can search the realtime Database for a specific child value and pull the rest of the Child Data that comes with it

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello is there a way I can pull a value from the real-time database and after that value is sought it pulls all the data that is associated with that search for example

I am pulling the whole child data using this method.

```
  const query = dataFirebase.ref("Item").orderByKey();
    query.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        const keyValue = childSnapshot.key;
        const fullData = childSnapshot.val();

        console.log(fullData)
    });
  });
```

The data for `Item` looks like

```
    {
      Item: {
        IDNumber1: {
          productDepartment: Cullinary,
          productStore: JCPenny
        }
        IDNumber2: {
          productDepartment: Cullinary,
          productStore: Macys
        }
        IDNumber3: {
          productDepartment: Home,
          productStore: JCPenny
        }
        IDNumber4: {
          productDepartment: Ties,
          productStore: JCPenny
        }
        IDNumber5: {
          productDepartment: Cullinary,
          productStore: Macys
        }
        IDNumber6: {
          productDepartment: Cullinary,
          productStore: Dillards
        }
        IDNumber7: {
          productDepartment: Ties,
          productStore: JCPenny
        }
      }
    }
```

The ID number is just a unique Identifier.

I am trying to have a search bar that looks up the values of a productDepartment such as "Culinary" and then have all the components that fit with that data like the productStore also show up so I can pull information from it more specifically.

So if I was to search Cullinary then IDNumber 1 2 5 and 6 would show.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `orderByChild()` and `equalTo()`:

```
const query = dataFirebase.ref("Item").orderByChild("productDepartment").equalTo("Culinary");
query.once("value")...
```

The rest of your code would remain the same.

For more information on this, see the Firebase [documentation on querying the Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: yeah I have looked at the documentation and found this and tried it out and it works perfectly.